# Algolia matching exact attribute

Tags: javascript, search, full-text-search, algolia

When I try to use

```
 restrictSearchableAttributes
```

using the Javascript client

I get

```
Invalid setting for restrictSearchableAttributes, attribute "field" is not in attributesToIndex
```

But I'm saving using the Laravel package and I already set the field for attributesToIndex there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `restrictSearchableAttributes` can only be used to restrict the searchable attributes to a subset of what your index settings describe.

Therefore, you need to ensure that `field` is in the `attributesToIndex` list (in your index settings) before being able to restrict the search on this attribute.

Comment: I forgot to call setSettings() on the backend. Thanks a lot man. It's working now.